# C# Console writeline print out generics list collection

Tags: c#, generic-collections

I need to print out the content of this Generic List with console writeline if is possible .Thanks in advance for your help.
This question is about this specific piece of code ,I did many search but without luck.
code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;                   
public class Program
{
public class Proto
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Object[] data {get;set;} 
}
public  void Main()
{

    metodo().ForEach(item => Console.Write(item + ","));
}

public List<Proto> metodo()
{
    Proto[] myproto = new Proto[5];
    List<Proto> mylist = new List<Proto>();
    for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
    {
        myproto[i] = new Proto {name = "blahblah",data = new Object[]{"dog","cat",2,3}};
        mylist.Add(myproto[i]);
    }
    int h = mylist.Count;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t",h);       
    return mylist;      
}
```

}## Heading ##

Comment: Please read [ask], you need to actually explain your problem. What do you expect this to do and what does it do?

Comment: Sorry,my fault i need only to print-out the content of List<Proto>(with console writeline) ...should be something like this [{name:"blablah",data:["dog","cat",2,3]},{},etc].

Comment: Think about the data type of `item` inside your ForEach delegate. You can't just print an object. You can either specify what you want in the `Console.WriteLine`method or override `ToString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override ToString():

```
public class Proto
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Object[] data {get;set;} 
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var dataAsString = data.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, t) => current + t.ToString());
        return name + dataAsString;  
    }
}
```

And use it

```
metodo().ForEach(item => Console.Write(item.ToString() + ","));
```

EDIT:
If you want it as JSON.
Install Json.Net from Nuget for your project and then

```
metodo().ForEach(item => Console.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item) + Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: ,yes it's ok ,but my final goal is to see the structure of object,i mean ,[{name:"cat",data:["dog","cat","",2,3]},{},{},{},{},{}],can you help me??

Comment: @Mercury77 Structure of current object(proto) or what? You can customize ToString() how you want

Comment: yes print out not only values of properties(name,data[]) but also the structure of object proto ,this will be then serialized and sent back to some web charts via JSON .

Comment: @Mercury77 And why not serialize to JSON first and then print as string? And how you will serialize to json string from output?

Comment: you're completely right ,this is not the code from webservice(serverside) is a semplification ,I wanted only to check the structure of data before serialize,plus I'm not using an ide right now and I'm not connected on the web server .Anyway an alert(JSON.stringify(someobject)) from browser reveals the structure of data is ok .Anyway thanks for your time I marked as answered .Overriding ToString() is really annoying ...I believed this time was not necessary.